# android: randomize JSON array number

Tags: android

> setImage(cachedImage1, image1, prjcts.get(x));
>             setImage(cachedImage2, image2, prjcts.get(x);
>             setImage(cachedImage3, image3, prjcts.get(x));

I need to replace x from prjcts.get(x) with a random number between 1 until the maximum entry on my JSON file. The maximum number should be felxible, I can add and delete the entry as much as I want. 
And one more thing, the numbers aren't allowed to be the same between each other.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `List list` and fill it with values from `1` to `jsonMax`.  Then use Java `Collections.shuffle(..)` to randomize the list.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int jsonMax = getMaxFromJSON(); //supplied by you
for(int i = 1; i<=jsonMax; i++)
    list.add(i);

Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Increment through `list` to get the random numbers.

Comment: So I did this, but then the program crashed: int i=0;
          List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          Random generator = new Random();
          int jsonMax = prjcts.size(); //supplied by you
          for(i = 1; i<=jsonMax; i++)
              list.add(i);
          Collections.shuffle(list);
          
          setImage(cachedImage1, image1, prjcts.get(i));

Comment: I can't help without seeing the stack trace.

Comment: Find the exception in the logcat.  You can type `adb logcat` into your command prompt if you have `adb` setup properly in your environment variables (in Windows).  It should also be available in your DDMS perspective in Eclipse.